# Are there any SATA HDD to PATA Docks?

Tags: sata, dock, pata

I have an oldish laptop (Acer Aspire 4710) with a SATA HDD. I wanted to extend the life of the laptop by adding an SSD drive. But I don't want to keep my data on the SSD (since it will wear out the SSD).

Is it possible to mount my old HDD drive into the optical drive bay? That way, I can keep the OS and apps on the SSD and my data on the HDD. It seems like the optical drive in my laptop is a PATA drive. Are there converters / docks available for doing this?

Comment: I believe there are, but they may be a bit too bulky to fit in there.  You might be better off just installing a SATA drive in there instead (you'll get better performance that way too).